# How to extract digits/numbers of an array one by one (outside of a loop) and not into another array (raw numbers)? Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

```
var num = 123;
var digits = num.toString().split('');
var arrayDigits = digits.map(Number)
console.log(arrayDigits);
```

In the next step, how can I extract values/numbers one by one out of arrayDigits after a loop and use each value (as number) outside of a forloop and ***array***?

Comment: `let [a, b, c] = arrayDigits`. The statement `var num = '';` is redundant and does nothing useful.

Comment: You have to use some iteration to get individual values out of an array.  If you need to use a number outside of the array you either have to put it somewhere - eg, individual variables - or call a function within the loop for each value.

Answer (score 1):

you can use array destructuring and extract the variables you want like so:

```js
var num = 123;
var digits = num.toString().split('');
var arrayDigits = digits.map(Number);

var [singles, tens, hundreds] = arrayDigits;
console.log(`${singles} ${tens} ${hundreds}`);
```

### You can red more about it here

[Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)